# What's the dating of the standard Akkadian version of the Gilgamesh Epic?

Tags: mesopotamia

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh) says:

> The most recent Akkadian version (c. 1200 BC), also referred to as the standard version, consisting of twelve tablets, was edited by Sin-liqe-unninni and was found in the Library of Ashurbanipal in Nineveh

But it appears that the tablets on which the epic was written date to 7th century BCE. Do I understand correctly that the Epic was compiled in 12th century BC, but the extant tablets containing it were created in 7th by a scribe for Assurbanipal?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you do understand correctly.

The best preserved tablets containing the standard Akkadian version were discovered in the [Library of Ashurbanipal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Ashurbanipal) in Nineveh by Hormuzd Rassam in 1853. These tablets are now held in the British Museum:

[image: The Flood Tablet - Epic of Gilgamesh]

- The Flood Tablet - Epic of Gilgamesh - Library of Ashurbanipal - image source [British Museum](http://www.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=278466&partId=1&searchText=mesopotamia&page=60) (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0)

---

However, even though the tablets recovered from the Library of Ashurbanipal in Nineveh had been written in the 7th century BCE, they included the the name of [Sîn-lēqi-unninni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%AEn-l%C4%93qi-unninni), who was the person that had compiled that version of the text sometime between 1300 BCE and 1000 BCE.

As a result, we can say that the tablets from the Library of Ashurbanipal were 7th century BCE copies of a much earlier (c. 1200 BCE) text.

---

It is worth stressing just how rare it was for the name of the person who compiled the text to be included in a cuneiform text at this date.  However, Sîn-lēqi-unninni was not the author of the Epic of Gilgamesh.

As Andrew George observed in the introduction to his 1999 translation:

> He [Sîn-lēqi-unninni] could not have been the original composer of the Babylonian epic, for a version of it already existed in the Old Babylonian period, but probably he gave it its final form and was thus responsible for the edition current in first-millennium libraries, the text that here we call the standard version.

- George, Andrew: [The epic of Gilgamesh: the Babylonian epic poem and other texts in Akkadian and Sumerian](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cUEOAAAAYAAJ), Penguin Books, 1999, p xxv

---

If you are interested in learning more about the origins of the Epic of Gilgamesh, and how the story  evolved, I'd highly recommend [The Babylonian Gilgamesh Epic: Introduction, Critical Edition and Cuneiform Texts](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303824234_The_Babylonian_Gilgamesh_Epic_Introduction_Critical_Edition_and_Cuneiform_Texts_2003) by [Dr Andrew George](https://www.soas.ac.uk/staff/staff30983.php) of SOAS (published by Oxford University Press in 2003).